# If AB = BA, what shape must A and B have? Assume A and B are matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having a hard time trying to comprehend this. How do I even start on proving the shape?

Comment: From your tag, I am assuming these are matrices?

Comment: Yes, sorry for being vague.

Comment: Notice that you can't say anything special about *each* matrix. For example if $B=0$ then $A$ could be anything.

Comment: If so, then you can show that these must commute.

Comment: I've heard that a subset of commuting matrices are symmetric matrices $A,B$ s.t. $AB$ is symmetric.

Comment: I think they're after "square" as the answer...

Answer (score 0):

In this question "shape" actually means "shape", the outer form of the matrix. So you are asked about the number of rows and columns. Assuming $A$ is a $k\times l$ matrix and $B$ is a $m\times n$ matrix, what does the equation $AB=BA$ tell you about $k,l,m,n$? No question is asked about the *entries* of $A,B$ (what $AB=BA$ tells about them is quite complicated, but you should ignore it).